# python flask hosting in AWS ubuntu(EC2)

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, apache2, amazon-ec2

I have followed [this](http://www.datasciencebytes.com/bytes/2015/02/24/running-a-flask-app-on-aws-ec2/) tutorial to run flask application using apache2 server. But after I followed its instructions and when opened the {publicDNS}/flaskapp page not found error occurred. How can i solve this problem.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes sometime to configure  the server. You have to restart it and see the public DNS